# Recursive JavaScript returning after first pass

Tags: javascript, recursion, marionette

I have the following recursive javascript function which is looping over the children of a backbone.marionette CollectionView that has children ItemViews that are in turn CollectionViews:

```
  findViewByCid: function(cid, children){
      var col = (arguments.length === 1) ? this.children : children;

      if(cid in col){
        return col[cid];
      }

      for(child in col){
        var grandChildren = col[child].children;

        if(cid in grandChildren){
          return grandChildren[cid];
        }

        if(grandChildren && (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(grandChildren))){
          return this.findViewByCid(cid, grandChildren);
        }
      }
    }
```

I am calling it like this:

var view =  DocumentManager.Documents.treeRoot.findViewByCid(model.cid);

The problem is the line:

```
return this.findViewByCid(cid, grandChildren);
```

If I have a hierarchy like this

```
c1
|_c2
  |_c3
|_c4
  |_c5
```

Then te return statement will cause the function to exit after passing th3 c2 node and never get to c4 etc.

If I remove the return statement, the correct child is found but null is returned.

How can I continue parsing the hierarchy and return a value?

Answer (score 0):

**return will exit your function**.

Try to save everything in a var and **return at the very end**, it can be an array if you need to return more than one value.
(and don't declare vars in a for-loop!)

Here is a **suggestion** :

```
findViewByCid: function(cid, children){
  var willBeReturned=[];
  var grandChildren;

  var col = (arguments.length === 1) ? this.children : children;

  if(cid in col){
    willBeReturned[willBeReturned.length] = col[cid];
  }
  for(child in col){
    grandChildren = col[child].children;

    if(cid in grandChildren){
      willBeReturned[willBeReturned.length] = grandChildren[cid];
    }

    if(grandChildren && (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(grandChildren))){
      willBeReturned[willBeReturned.length] = this.findViewByCid(cid, grandChildren);
    }
  }
  return willBeReturned;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to return only if something was found, else the `return` statement will break your loop without having searched the other children. It is a simple [depth-first-search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) what you want.

Assuming the function is on the prototype of each child (not only on the root node):

```
findViewByCid: function(cid) {
    var col = this.children;
    if (!col) // break if the node has no children
        return false;
    if (cid in col) // look for cid and return the node if one found
        return col[cid];
    for (var child in col) {
        // search through each child and return the result if something is found
        var found = col[child].findViewByCid(cid);
        if (found)
            return found;
    }
    // else nothing was found
    return false;
}
```

Or having a function taking a node as an argument:

```
function findViewByCid(cid, node) {
    var col = node.children;
    if (!col)
        return false;
    if (cid in col)
        return col[cid];
    for (var child in col) {
        var found = findViewByCid(cid, col[child]);
        if (found)
            return found;
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, it seems this algorithm will not be able to find the root node. It would be better if you could identify the current node by `cid`, instead of looking at all of its children:

```
if (this /*… is what we have searched for */)
    return this;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
findViewByCid: function(cid, children) {
    var col = (arguments.length === 1) ? this.children : children;

    if(cid in col){
        return col[cid];
    }       
    for(var childKey in col) {
        var grandChildren = col[childKey].children,
            childView;

        if (grandChildren) {
            childView = this.findViewByCid(cid, grandChildren);
        }

        if (childView) {
            return childView;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

First of all, this looks like Backbone.js, it may be helpful to tag it if it is.  I feel like people might have struggled with similar problems and know better ways to store references to views.

You only want to return something if it was found... just using return on the first recursive call will force the method to stop execution upon searching the first set of grandchildren, even if nothing was found.

I would also add a var in front of the new variable you're introducing in your for loop - without it, the variable is going to be global.

Comment: It is backbone.marionette and I am iterating over a CollectionView with an ItemView that is a CollectionView making it a bit more complex than usual.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with and it is backbone.marionette, iterating over  a collectionView with an itemView of a CollectionView:

```
findViewByCid: function(cid){
  var self = this,
      ret;

  function findView(cid, children){
    var col = (arguments.length === 1) ? self.children : children,
    grandChildren;

    if(cid in col){
      ret = col[cid];
    }

    for(child in col){
      grandChildren = col[child].children;

      if(cid in grandChildren){
        ret = grandChildren[cid];
      }

      if(grandChildren && (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(grandChildren))){
        findView(cid, grandChildren);
      }
    }
  };

  findView(cid);

  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the line if (cid in col) does not what you want to do. Try

```
findViewByCid: function(cid, children){
  if (this.cid === cid) return this;

  var col = (arguments.length === 1) ? this.children : children;
  for(var childI in col){
    var child = col[childI];

    if (child.cid === cid) {
      return child;
    }

    var grandChildren = child.children;
    if(grandChildren && (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(grandChildren))){
      return this.findViewByCid(cid, grandChildren);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hard to explain. consider cid is 5. cid in model checks if there is model[5] what not is the same as model['cid'] === 5 or model.cid === 5.